# Jordan form transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix with eigenvalues 1 and 0 only. Suppose $J=PAP^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan form. How to show that $P$ only have entries 0 and 1? Any hints, idea?

Answer (score 1):

There need not exist an invertible $P$ with entries $0$ and $1$ such that $J = PAP^{-1}$.  In particular, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&2\\0&0}
$$
whose Jordan form is
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
The first column of $P^{-1}$ is an eigenvector of $A$, and the second column is the associated generalized eigenvector.

So, we must have
$$
P^{-1} = \alpha \pmatrix{1&\beta\\0&1/2}
$$
Which means that
$$
P = \frac 1{\alpha}\pmatrix{1&-2\beta\\0&2}
$$

Thus, there is no suitable $P$ containing only $0$s and $1$s.